# Is it possible to use break in in-line for in python

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension

I am wring a python application that is iterating through file list. I want to get a few items based on some condition. I know that the files are listed by modified time and I want to iterate only through the one that are modified soon before 60 seconds. So I do this:

```
t = int(datetime.now().strftime('%s'))
get_quie = [[f.filename, f.st_size]
            for f in reversed(sftp.listdir_attr('./'))
            if t - f.st_mtime < 60 or t - f.st_atime < 60 ]
```

I want to add condition that breaks out of this for loop when the difference between `t` and `f.st_mtime` starts to grow.

Is it possible to do it in in-line for loop or I should use the regular `for x in list` loop?

Comment: You can't use `break` in a list comprehension, no. `break` is a statement, a list comprehension is an expression; you can't put statements in expressions.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. That was the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `break` in a list comprehension, no. `break` is a statement, a list comprehension is an expression; you can't put statements in expressions.

You'll either have to use a regular `for` loop (which is a statement that can contain other statements), or find a way to add on a `if <condition>` filter to the list comprehension that skips the rest of the elements in the loop.

Answer (score 2):

This is what [takewhile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile)  will do. It'll take all elements while a condition is satisfied. When the condition is not satisfied, it'll essentially "break":

```
from itertools import takewhile

...
get_quie = [
    [f.filename, f.st_size]
    for f in takewhile(
        lambda f: t - f.st_mtime < 60 or t - f.st_atime < 60,
        reversed(sftp.listdir_attr('./'))
    )
]
```

Comment: Thank you. That is really good example. I've looked in the documentation and what it does is creating a function that handles the logic. I was searching for solution without additional functions. It is still highly usable  functionality. The `lambda` keyword is new to me!

Answer (score 0):

No, although they both use `for`, a for-statement is quite different from a list comprehension. The list comprehension is quite restrictive in what it may contain (basically `for <target> in <array> if <condition>`, you can repeat the beginning an leav the end out - but that's about it).